# If $\|x_k - x_{k-1}\| \le \frac{1} {k^2}$, what is the limit of $\lim_{k \to \infty} (k x_k - (k-1) x_{k-1})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $\{x_k\} \subseteq X$ where $X$ is a Banach space. $\{x_k\}$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\|x_k - x_{k-1} \| \le \frac 1 {k^2}.
\end{align*}
It is clear $\{x_k\}$ is convergent since for sufficiently large $n, m$,
\begin{align*}
\|x_n - x_m\| \le \sum_{j=n}^m \frac 1 {j^2} \le \varepsilon. 
\end{align*}
I would like to know whether it makes sense to consider the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \left( k x_k - (k-1) x_{k-1} \right)$. If it makes sense, is the computation following correct?
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left( k(x_k - x_{k-1}) + x_{k-1} \right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} k(x_k - x_{k-1}) + \lim_{k \to \infty} x_{k-1} = x \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in any normed space, if $x_n \to a$ and $y_n \to b$ then $x_n+y_n \to a+b$.

Also, note that 
$$\| k(x_k - x_{k-1}) \| = |k| \|x_k - x_{k-1} \| \leq \frac{1}{k}$$
implies 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} (k(x_k - x_{k-1})) =0 $$

In general $x_n \to a$ in a normed space if and only if $\|x_n-a \| \to 0$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to estimate how fast $x_n \to a$ as a function of $k$ in this scenario?

Comment: @jing007 Yes, $$\|x_n -a \| \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \| x_k -x_{k+1} \| \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{n}  $$ since the last series is telescopic.

Comment: @jing007 If you need more details for any step in the computation, let me know.