# Convergence rate if a sequence $\{x_k\}$ satisfies that $x_{k} - x_{k-1} \le \frac {1} {k^{p}}$ where $p >1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, rate-of-convergence

Suppose $\{x_k\} \subseteq X$ where $X$ is a Banach space. $\{x_k\}$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\|x_k - x_{k-1} \| \le \frac 1 {k^p},
\end{align*}
where $1 < p < 2$. The sequence is clearly Cauchy and convergent. Let $x$ be the limit point. I am wondering whether we could get some convergence rate inequality
\begin{align*}
\|x_k - x\| \le f(k),
\end{align*}
where $f(k)$ is some function of $k$.

We clearly can do this for $p=2$. That is $\|x_k -x\| \le \frac 1 k$ by telescoping. The answer is in the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618330/if-x-k-x-k-1-le-frac1-k2-what-is-the-limit-of-lim-k-to-in/2618336?noredirect=1#comment5407752_2618336) I asked before (actually comments in the accepted answer). But I am not sure if we can still use the telescoping technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\|x_k-x\|=\left\|\sum_{i=k}^\infty x_i-x_{i+1}\right\|\leq\sum_{i=k}^\infty\|x_i-x_{i+1}\|\leq\sum_{i=k}^\infty\frac{1}{i^p}.$$
The last series is most easily estimated using an integral:
$$\sum_{i=k}^\infty\frac{1}{i^p}\leq\sum_{i=k}^\infty\int_{i-1}^i\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p}=\int_{k-1}^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^p}=\frac{1}{p-1}\frac{1}{(k-1)^{p-1}}.$$